# scheb/two_factor_bundle: how to use exclude_pattern for authenticated route?

Tags: php, listener, symfony, two-factor-authentication

I'm using Scheb's [two factor bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/scheb/two-factor-bundle) in a Symfony3 project and I'd like to handle the `exclude_pattern` parameter differently than it does, but I don't know how.

Normally, `exclude_pattern` is used to exclude an **unauthenticated** route from the two-factor authentication, like debug pages or static content:

```
# config/config.yml

scheb_two_factor:
    ...
    exclude_pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
```

its behavior being implemented like this:

```
/* vendor/scheb/two-factor-bundle/Security/TwoFactor/EventListener/RequestListener.php */

public function onCoreRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    // Exclude path
    if ($this->excludePattern !== null && preg_match('#'.$this->excludePattern.'#', $request->getPathInfo())) {
        return;
    }

    ...

}
```

I'd like to handle `exclude_pattern` also for **authenticated** routes, so that I can skip two-factor authentication when I call them. For *authenticated* I mean within `access_control` section under `security.yml`, like this:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/test, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Right now, if I add an authenticated route under exclude_pattern, all I get is a *AccessDeniedException*, probably because the bundle requires that the `access_decision_manager` parameter to be set as `strategy: unanimous`.

The purpose is long to tell and English is not my native language, but if you really need to know it I can try to explain.

I tagged the question with both symfony3 and symfony2 because I'm using Symfony 3.0 but I'm pretty sure it's identical in Symfony 2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by overriding the Voter class from the bundle:

```
// AppBundle/Security/TwoFactor/Voter.php

namespace AppBundle\Security\TwoFactor;
use Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Security\TwoFactor\Session\SessionFlagManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class Voter extends \Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Security\TwoFactor\Voter
{


    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $excludePattern;

    /**
     * Voter constructor.
     * @param SessionFlagManager $sessionFlagManager
     * @param array $providers
     * @param $excludePattern
     */
    public function __construct(SessionFlagManager $sessionFlagManager, array $providers, $excludePattern)
    {

        parent::__construct($sessionFlagManager, $providers);
        $this->excludePattern = $excludePattern;
    }

    /**
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @param mixed          $object
     * @param array          $attributes
     *
     * @return mixed result
     */
    public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {

        if ($this->excludePattern !== null && preg_match('#'.$this->excludePattern.'#', $object->getPathInfo()))
        {
            return true;
        }

        parent::vote($token, $object, $attributes);
    }

}
```

---

```
# app/config/services.yml

services:
    ...
    scheb_two_factor.security_voter:
    class: 'AppBundle\Security\TwoFactor\Voter'
    arguments:
        - '@scheb_two_factor.session_flag_manager'
        - ~
        - '%scheb_two_factor.exclude_pattern%'
```

This way, whenever the *GetResponseEvent* is triggered, the right *Voter* is invoked which votes `true` if the `exclude_pattern` matches the path.